# Exponential generating function of product

Tags: generating-functions, bernoulli-numbers

It needs to find an exponential generating function for the next sequence: $(2^n-1)B_n$. Where $B_n$ is the n-th number of Bernoulli. I found that exponential generating function for sequence of $B_n$ is $B(t)=t/(e^t-1)$. But I do not know what to do with $2^nB_n$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: what happens if you replace $t$ by $2t$ ?

Comment: I think about it, but then it seemed very easy to me and I think that there is not right way of solution

Comment: The right answer is $2t/(e^{2t}-1)$?

Comment: the expansion in powers of $t$ will be replaced by the expansion if powers of $(2t)$ so....

Comment: so $2t/(e^{2t}-1)$?

Comment: yes this is the correct generating function for $2^n\,B_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: what happens if you replace $t$ by $2t$ ?
Hint 2: subtract the two generating functions.